# How to sync photos automatically with database in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django.

I'm working on a project which requires Django. In this project, a program captures photos via camera continuously , and stores them in path`C:\Users\admin\Pictures`.

Now I want a Django APP to sync these photos with database automatically, rather than log in Django admin site and upload them manually. How to do that correctly in Django?

Here is **models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

# Create your models here.

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    original = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.IMAGE_PREFIX, default='/tmp/none.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I wrote the script just trying to sync these photos:

```
import os
import django

django.setup()

from gallery.models import Image    

path = r"C:\Users\admin\Pictures"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filePath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    thisFile = open(filePath, 'rb')
    new_img = Image(original=thisFile, title=filename)
    new_img.save()
```

But I got error messages as follow:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaOey.jpg)

I guess there must be something missed when I tried to pass `thisFile` to `Image()`, but I just don't know how to fix it.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: does this help you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/GE5eCdse_OQ ???

Answer (score 0):

`FileField` expects django `File` object.

```
import os
import django
from django.core.files import File

django.setup()

from gallery.models import Image    

path = r"C:\Users\admin\Pictures"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filePath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    thisFile = File(open(filePath, 'rb'))
    new_img = Image(original=thisFile, title=filename)
    new_img.save()
```